# hidding api with interfaces in Java

Tags: java, api, interface

Can somebody explain me what "hidding api with interfaces in Java" means ?
How can I use the API functions by means of interfaces ?
I would need an small working example to understand the how the interfaces hides the api non public parts, and how can I use the api puplic parts in the same time.

Thanks in advance.

THANKS GUYS FOR THE QUICK REPLY, GIVE ME TIME TO THINK OVER THE ANSWERS.
LAST BUT NOT LEAST THANKS FOR YOUR TIME AND EFFORT!

**II.** My second question is : What happens in the background this case below ?

```
IBinaryOperation op = BinaryOperationProvider.getOperation("multiply");

or 

List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Its not clear for me because the interfaces consist of methods' declarations that's why i dont understand what could happened in the lines above.
Is there any meaning of the equality between empty method of used interfaces and objects ?
Sorry for my weak English.

Answer (score 6):

For instance, you may declare and create a list of strings as follows:

```
List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

[List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is the type of `myList`. It is an interface. It means that all subsequent calls to methods of `myList` will be done *through* the interface: you may only call methods declared in the `List` interface.

However, the concrete class of the object is [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), that contains more methods, some of them reflecting the structure of a *linked list* (for instance `addFirst` and `addLast`). But these methods are *hidden* because of the way you declared the variable. You chose to access the object through a given (restrictive) interface.

It may seem restrictive, but it also means that you can change your code at any time, and replace the concrete class `LinkedList` with any other class that implements the `List` interface, for example [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if you have time can answer my second question, pls see the II. part.

Comment: In practice only instances of *concrete* classes are created at run-time. In contrast, interfaces are used by the compiler to perform static type-checking. Therefore the compiler detects if you try to call a hidden method.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you expose your API, you should hide the implementation details as much as possible and expose it via simple interfaces.

For e.g. Suppose that you give an api for adding two numbers.

**Soln1 (Bad soln)** Give the following class to client

```
public class Adder {
    public void setA() {..}

    public void setB() {..}

    public int add() { return A + B; }  
}
```

**Soln 2** (better soln): Give the following interface to the client.

```
public interface Adder {
    public int add(int a, int b);

}
```

Now  why is soln 2 a better solution. If you had given user the first soln. The client is bound to the class Adder. Suppose later you have a new implementation of addition that could add the numbers in the cloud(over-imaginative :)), you may have to as the client to change their code to use the new class.

Instead if you just give them the interface, you could provide many implementation and have a factory mechanism to choose the suitable implementation.

Comment: Because of my lack of knowledge I can't imagine how it is used in the reality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if you have time can answer my second question, pls see the II. part.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example that uses an interface:

```
public interface IBinaryOperation {
    public int performOp(int a, int b);
}

private class MultiplicationProvider implements IBinaryOperation {
    public int performOp(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}

public class BinaryOperationProvider {
    static IBinaryOperation getOperation(String name) {
        if ("multiply".equals(name)) {
            return new MultiplicationProvider();
        } else if ("add".equals("name)) {
            return new AdditionProvider();
        } // ...
    }
}
```

You would use this like:

```
IBinaryOperation op = BinaryOperationProvider.getOperation("multiply");
int c = op.performOp(a, b);
```

In the above example, `MultiplicationProvider` is completely private to the implementation of the API. The only public part is the `IBinaryOperation` interface, and the `BinaryOperationProvider` class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if you have time can you answer my second question, pls see the II. part.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, what's "hidden" is not the API, but the implementation. Most clients of List (to use an example above) don't need to know which kind of List is actually being used. (Just like most TCP/IP clients don't need to know anything in particular about the network they're using -- just that it supports the standard connection abstraction.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if you have time can answer my second question, pls see the II. part.

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand, I'm afraid. In the case with "new LinkedList", the code is creating an instance of a class that implements an interface. In the other, it's calling some unknown method that provides some implementation of an interface. Don't know whether that helps you.

Comment: Hello Vance, I understood what happens when we are using : List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
It is just assigning an typed reference (LinkedList) to a similar reference List<String>. Similar because they are using the some interface.In shortm, it is about assigning same typed references to each other Thanks for your time and effort.